# jQuery is not defined for angular 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, angular

I am trying to use ng2-datetime. However, when I follow the instruction and installed npm install --save ng2-datetime, I get the following error.

[image: jQuery not defined]

I have tried running the following npm install but it doesnt fix anything.

```
 npm install jquery --save 
 npm install @types/jquery --save-dev
```

My package.json file

```json
{
  "name": "timesheet-web-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/core": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/http": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/router": "^3.3.1",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-alpha.18",
    "angularfire2": "^2.0.0-beta.7",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-alpha.6",
    "bootstrap-datepicker": "^1.6.4",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "firebase": "^3.6.6",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "ng2-datetime": "^1.2.2",
    "ng2-datetime-picker": "^0.12.7",
    "ng2-file-upload": "^1.2.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.1",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.3.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/jquery": "^2.0.39",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.24",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0-beta.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
    "protractor": "~4.0.13",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "^4.0.2",
    "typescript": "~2.0.3"
  }
}
```

[image: My folder structure]

Comment: Did you imported it with webpack or your module bundler?

Comment: I dont have webpack. I just install everything through npm install --save and the dependencies gets loaded in node_module file.

Comment: post your angular code please

Comment: I think forgot to import it in app.module.ts. Does it get included in the imports, declarations,  or providers?

Comment: You need to use any module bundler. Do you use systemjs ? Please post your `package.json` file

Comment: I'm sorry I am notexactly sure what module bundle is at this stage of my programming life. I have included my package.json file and my folder structure if that helps? I created my project with angular CLI with command ng new <projectName>

Comment: Yeah you have that file man. https://i.gyazo.com/aafc7cef8467a1e9873e75bf7756c169.png

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You need to import jquery with `angular-cli`.
Edit your `angular-cli.json` file.

Find `script` array and add jquery.

```json
"scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
],
```

Comment: Hey man. Thanks for the answer. I have seen this somewhere on SO. However, I do not have that file in  my project folders though....

Comment: If you using `angular-cli` you must have this file. It's config file for it.

Comment: You can read about global library installation more here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#global-library-installation

Comment: Yeah you have that file man. :D https://i.gyazo.com/aafc7cef8467a1e9873e75bf7756c169.png

Comment: Yeh man. Sorry I must be blind. I was thinking about system.config.js which I saw in the other post that I dont have. Trying the solutions now!. Cheers

Comment: This solution works! However, I am getting some error on the framework itself. But that is a different question. Thanks mate.

Comment: In Angular version 8 I can not find that file in my project!

Comment: I am getting this error: Script file ../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js does not exist after I added this line to angular.json file

Answer (score 12):

Wasted a good amount of time, here is what I did and **didn't** help.

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clear --force
npm cache clean
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

and all other usual things,

- clear browser cache
- restart browser
- kill and re-run ng serve

---

**In my case I had to do the following:**

```
npm install --save @types/jquery
```

Import jquery in the .angular-cli.json:

```json
"scripts": [
     "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"
],
```

change code from

```
import $ from 'jquery';
```

to

```
import * as jquery from 'jquery';
```

**note:** issue started after angular upgrade from 4.2 to 5.2

Comment: Where do you write the import statements? I'm writing them in the AppModule but no success.

Comment: in the component files which use jquery

Comment: Your answer is correct but do you know why we need to specify jQuery in scripts and why this is not needed for bootstrap, popper etc.? They just work once installed using npm but jQuery doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';

window['$'] = window['jQuery'] = $;
```

The second line will fix your issue!